# Feed doesn't show latest messages

Tags: feeds

I have a website containing different feeds.
Unfortunately I have 1 important newsfeed who doesn't get updated.

I have searched all possible forums, without success.

This is how it shows:
http://www.tri-portaal.be/aggregator/sources/1

Here is the feed it should display:
http://3athlon.be/feed/

I am using [drupal 7.43](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/7.43)

I think that the problem is not crone related, as all my other feeds do update.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Did you check in **Admin => Reports => Recent Log messages**, if there are any errors while importing these feeds? Also check **Update interval** in your aggregator setting just to make sure it is not too long.

Comment: Hello, I've indeed a CRON error on the 4 last articles not loading. This is the error: PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x89" ...' for column 'description' at row 1.... Why is this only happening for these last posts? And how can I work around this error?

Comment: This is the end of the failure description:  qua beleving?</span></p> [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => http://3athlon.be/?p=14222 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 1456405909 [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 1 ) in aggregator_save_item() (line 163 of /customers/e/b/8/tri-portaal.be/httpd.www/modules/aggregator/aggregator.processor.inc). I guess I have to go l look somewhere in that file.

Comment: This is the aggregator_save_item() code on line 151 to 163:function aggregator_save_item($edit) {
  if ($edit['title'] && empty($edit['iid'])) {
    $edit['iid'] = db_insert('aggregator_item')
      ->fields(array(
        'title' => $edit['title'],
        'link' => $edit['link'],
        'author' => $edit['author'],
        'description' => $edit['description'],
        'guid' => $edit['guid'],
        'timestamp' => $edit['timestamp'],
        'fid' => $edit['fid'],
      ))
      ->execute();

Comment: This is from the feeds log: 'timestamp' => 1456405909, The timestamp seems indeed strange. Is there a way I can import the feed without the timestamp?

Comment: Seems like UTF-8 encoding issue. Quick fix for this is changing column encoding from [utf8 to utfmb4](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10959780/377342).

Comment: thank you for your support! This might seem logical. But I have no idea on what action I should undertake now. I tried changing in PHPmyAdmin the following databases to UTF8mb4: aggregator_categorie, aggregator_categorie_feed, aggregator_categorie_item, aggregator_feed, aggregator_item, date_formats, date format_locale and date_format_type. Is this the correct way of working? Problem is not solved yet.

Comment: I tried this allready, found in one of the comments of the issue you linked to:  
# For each database: ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci; # For each table: ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci; # For each column: ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci; But until now there is no improvement.

Comment: I think we can exclude this solution. On 3athlon.nl, where they do not have a problem to show this feed they are also working in UTF8.

Comment: The FEEDS module does a correct import. So the problem is very probably related to the aggregator module.

Comment: Problem is not solved yet.

Comment: Can you share the exact output you're getting in recent log messages, that will help debug more and fix the issue.

Comment: @Yogesh this is the feeds log. It's the same error for the other messages he fails to import: [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LtiYT1SbuTVOylRriAd1GBJtulsH0ia8tceLVWuCZRc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I've tried importing the output from document link you've shared, and first time it threw same error you mentioned, after which I changed the character encoding of **description** column in **aggregator_item** table (see query below) and then again tried importing that data again and it went through successfully. Query to update character set of column `ALTER TABLE aggregator_item CHANGE description description LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Body of the feed item.';`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Problem remains. Here you can see screensot of my phpadmin. I allready tried changing all the char sets myself after you adviced it. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2hsX1DUzEYZUlZXRjQyTXJQOXc/view?usp=sharing) Thank you for your efforts anyway. @Yogesh

Comment: [here] (http://www.tri-portaal.be/aggregator/sources/40) you can see there came 2 new artikels in the list. alltough it are the oldes. The newest still don't appear. Why were these articles not shown for one week and are they showing up nog? The timestamp hasn't changed.

Comment: Here I have annother issue with the aggregator. This link shows in the aggregator API 4 new items. But, when I open the [link](http://www.tri-portaal.be/aggregator/sources/33) it shows an empty list.

Comment: Today I can report the problem solved itself after 2 weeks. I hope it stays like this. There was probably somthing in the content that disturbed the aggregator module.